# Camera in android emulator

Tags: android, android-camera

I use android SDK 4.0.3 and eclipse Indigo and I'm trying to develop an application which uses a camera. When I take a photo, this message appears:

> Unfortunately, camera has stopped.

In the eclipse console:

> emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_frame: Unable to obtain first video frame from the camera '/dev/video0' in 2009 milliseconds: Resource temporarily unavailable.

My OS is Debian Squeeze. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Same issue on a MacBook Pro as well. Hopeless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emulator camera does not work properly .You must try it on Real Device.

Comment: A little trick that works sometimes: use the simulated camera instead of your laptop's camera (set that in Android Device Manager) which is less consuming, and thus more chances to avoid the error. Also, if you open first the original camera application, then your application has also little bit better odds to not to get the error (super weird...)

Answer (score 0):

As Shahzad imam said, you can't use camera on emulator.

But if can't buy real device and you're really need camera you can try to translate video to network from your PC and then handle it in Android, as it a real camera. Or, if you just need photo, you can use some picture instead.