# Fail to connect to the camera service, using the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Today I wanted to test an App i have developed few days ago and the camers service is part of it.
Today, i wanted to test that App on the EMULATOR, but i found the the logcat says:

```
Fail to connect to the camera service
```

despit of, i have tested the same app using the EMULATOR before, and it worked  correctly, but today, i received this error.

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidbook.SaveImgPathSQLite"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SaveImg"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

logcat:

```
    06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:258)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:235)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at amr.NAVKA_Projekt.MPTest.CameraSurface.surfaceCreated(CameraSurface.java:44)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-08 05:28:46.539: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please show your code, logcat and android-manifest

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133200/camera-in-android-emulator/9133457#9133457

Comment: but i tested the sam app 2 days ago using the emulator !

Comment: Ohk!!!!! it can but most of da tym it fails .It happened same to me.Its better to follow Yasir's link ,coz that answer is accepted 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use application that use camera services

if you really want to use it on emulator [follow this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image/1283741#1283741)